# Highcharts clickhandler and accessing context

Tags: highcharts, angular5

I am sure there is an answer to this question somewhere on Stackoverfow, I sadly couldnt find it.
I often have the problem of not beeing able to access the context (this) inside of eventhandlers.
In this particular example its in a highcharts click handler.
The datautils is not accessible inside of the clickhandler.

```
  constructor(private zone: NgZone,
              public _dataUtils: DataUtils) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lineChart = this.getLineChart(this.series
  }

  private getLineChart(series{
    return new Chart({
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          cursor: 'pointer',
            events: {
              click: this.chartClick,
          },
        },
      },
      series: [series]
    });
  }

  chartClick = function(event) {
    this._dataUtils.reCalculateData([event.point.series.name + '#' + event.point.name]);
  };
```

If you refer me to a topic that has answered this question I am more than happy! 
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the so called arrow function.
A good read on that is [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html)

```
chartClick = (event) => {
  //logic with access to context
}
```